# Get minimum without using row number/window function in Bigquery

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery, min

I have a table like as shown below

[image]

What I would like to do is get the minimum of each subject. Though I am able to do this with `row_number` function, I would like to do this with `groupby` and `min()` approach. But it doesn't work.

**row_number approach** - works fine

```
SELECT * FROM (select subject_id,value,id,min_time,max_time,time_1,
row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY subject_id ORDER BY value) AS rank
from table A) WHERE RANK = 1
```

**min() approach** - doesn't work

```
select subject_id,id,min_time,max_time,time_1,min(value) from table A
GROUP BY SUBJECT_ID,id
```

As you can see just the two columns `(subject_id and id)` is enough to group the items together. They will help differentiate the group. But why am I not able to use the other columns in select clause. If I use the other columns, I may not get the expected output because `time_1` has different values.

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like below-

```
SELECT 
A.subject_id,
A.id,
A.min_time,
A.max_time,
A.time_1,
A.value 
FROM table A
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT subject_id, MIN(value) Value
    FROM table
    GROUP BY subject_id
) B ON A.subject_id = B.subject_id
AND A.Value = B.Value
```

If you do not required to select Time_1 column's value, this following query will work (As I can see values in column min_time and max_time is same for the same group)-

```
SELECT 
A.subject_id,A.id,A.min_time,A.max_time,
--A.time_1,
MIN(A.value) 
FROM table A
GROUP BY 
A.subject_id,A.id,A.min_time,A.max_time
```

Finally, the best approach is if you can apply something like CAST(Time_1 AS DATE) on your time column. This will consider only the date part regardless of the time part. The query will be

```
SELECT 
A.subject_id,A.id,A.min_time,A.max_time,
CAST(A.time_1 AS DATE) Time_1,
MIN(A.value) 
FROM table A
GROUP BY 
A.subject_id,A.id,A.min_time,A.max_time,
CAST(A.time_1 AS DATE) 
-- Make sure the syntax of CAST AS DATE 
-- in BigQuery is as I written here or bit different.
```

Comment: Thank you. Upvoted. can you let me know what's wrong with my `min` appraoch. When those two columns can help us differentiate, why do we have to still use other columns in group by caluse

Comment: In your MIN() approach, you have selected columns - subject_id, id, min_time, max_time, time_1 but only added columns SUBJECT_ID, id in the GROUP BY which is not allowed. All non aggregated columns must be part of GROUP BY. But if you do that, you will not get your expected data as there are differences in Time_1 column and as a result, If you apply GROUP BY on Time_1 column, you will get more row then expected.

Comment: Exactly. But when these two columns i.e is `subject_id` and `id` can help us differentiate the groups, why do I have to be bothered about the variations in time column.

Comment: If you wants to select Time_1 column value, you have to think about it. But if you do not required values from that column, applying GROUP BY on all other columns will work. Just avoid Time_1 from the selection and GROUP BY. An alternative is if you can Apply something like CAST(Time_1 AS DATE), this will also work if dates re same for same group's data.

Comment: btw if i am comparing dates, is it the right way to do? `c.charttime <= cast(d.max_time as datetime)`. Just asking. not w.r.t to this question

Comment: This is difficult to say from my side with having much data level experience and your requirement. But you can do this type of checking as per your requirement. Consider time part is essential or not in your process.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200090/discussion-between-ssmk-and-mkrabbani).

Answer (score 4):

In BigQuery you can use aggregation for this:

```
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(a ORDER BY value LIMIT 1)[SAFE_OFFSET(1)].*
FROM table A
GROUP BY SUBJECT_ID;
```

This uses `ARRAY_AGG()` to aggregate each record (the `a` in the argument list).  `ARRAY_AGG()` allows you to order the result (by `value`) and to limit the size of the array.  The latter is important for performance.

After you concatenate the arrays, you want the first element.  The `.*` transforms the record referred to by `a` to the component columns.

I'm not sure why you don't want to use `ROW_NUMBER()`.  If the problem is the lingering `rank` column, you an easily remove it:

```
SELECT a.* EXCEPT (rank)
FROM (SELECT a.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY subject_id ORDER BY value) AS rank
      FROM A
     ) a
WHERE RANK = 1;
```

Comment: Would you mind providing explanation on how this works? it will be helpful. Upvoted

Comment: Actually I am curious to know about the Bigquery approach functions

Comment: `a` represents each row.?

Comment: Can you help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58146083/elegant-and-efficient-way-to-write-sql-in-bigquery

Comment: BigQuery can treat rows as structs (records).  Using the table alias refers to the entire row as a struct.

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and is most efficient way for such cases like in  your question

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY value LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
GROUP BY subject_id
```

Using ROW_NUMBER is not efficient and in many cases lead to Resources exceeded error.

Note: self join is also very ineffective way of achieving your objective

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but here is a cte-based approach which made sense to me:

```
with mins as (
   select subject_id, id, min(value) as min_value
   from table
   group by subject_id, id
)
select distinct t.subject_id, t.id, t.time_1, t.min_time, t.max_time, m.min_value
from table t
join mins m on m.subject_id = t.subject_id and m.id = t.id
```