# Elegant and efficient way to write minimum in bigquery

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

I have a table structure like as shown below

[image]

What I am trying to do is find the minimum for each group of items. I have to keep finding minimums for different group of itemids. Though my code works, am sure this isn't the elegant and efficient way to do it.

**finding minimum WHERE itemid IN (1,2)**

```
select subject_id,icu_id,value as min_val_1 FROM
(SELECT c.subject_id,c.time_1,d.min_time,d.max_time,c.value,c.icu_id,
row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY c.subject_id ORDER BY c.value,c.time_1) AS rank
from table_1 d
left join table_2 c 
on c.subject_id = d.subject_id and (c.icu_id = d.icu_id_1 or c.icu_id = d.icu_id_2)
where c. itemid in 
(1,2)) SBP
where rank = 1
order by subject_id,charttime
```

**finding minimum where itemid in (3,4)**

```
select subject_id,icu_id,value as min_val_2 FROM
(SELECT c.subject_id,c.time_1,d.min_time,d.max_time,c.value,c.icu_id,
row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY c.subject_id ORDER BY c.value,c.time_1) AS rank
from table_1 d
left join table_2 c 
on c.subject_id = d.subject_id and (c.icu_id = d.icu_id_1 or c.icu_id = d.icu_id_2)
where c. itemid in 
(3,4)) SBP
where rank = 1
order by subject_id
```

As you can see everything is same. Only difference is the itemid. Is there any elegant way to join/merge these two? can you help me?

I expect my output to be like this?

[image]

Comment: What does this mean:  "What I am trying to do is find the minimum for each group of items. "  Minimum of *what*?  What *groups* of items?  Please clarify.

Comment: Minimum of value based on item ids for each subject

Comment: Both the answers were good and upvoted. I chose to mark Mikhail answer as solution as it was more helpful and in line with my logic. Appreciate their input.

Comment: . . In this case (which I think is admittedly uncommon), I think my solution is simpler than Mikhail's.  His answers are usually spot-on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and leaves your original query fully intact while just adding missing peaces (added comments so you can see those few changes/additions)

```
#standardSQL 
SELECT 
  subject_id,
  icu_id,
  MAX(IF(grp = 1, value, NULL)) AS min_val_1,   -- changed
  MAX(IF(grp = 2, value, NULL)) AS min_val_2    -- changed
FROM (
  SELECT 
    c.subject_id,
    c.time_1,
    d.min_time,
    d.max_time,
    c.value,c.icu_id,
    -- in below row - added element to PARTITION BY
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.subject_id, CASE WHEN c.itemid IN (1, 2) THEN 1 WHEN c.itemid IN (3, 4) THEN 2 END ORDER BY c.value, c.time_1) AS RANK,
    CASE WHEN c.itemid IN (1, 2) THEN 1 WHEN c.itemid IN (3, 4) THEN 2 END grp  -- added
  FROM table_1 d
  LEFT JOIN table_2 c 
  ON c.subject_id = d.subject_id AND (c.icu_id = d.icu_id_1 OR c.icu_id = d.icu_id_2)
  WHERE c.itemid IN (1, 2, 3, 4)  -- changed
) SBP
WHERE RANK = 1
GROUP BY subject_id, icu_id  -- added
ORDER BY subject_id
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - result is

```
Row subject_id  icu_id  min_val_1   min_val_2    
1   124         A1      10          19   
2   199         B2      21          21
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. Upvoted. However, I have a question. As I am new to query, trying to understand. If the below answer by Gordon is also gonna give the same output, isn't it easy to write just two lines instead of such a long query.is there any difference between two answers that I am missing it?

Comment: I don't want to criticize other answer(s) - but in short - it does not really fully reflect your question and example you presented as it does not even involve table_1 at all while it is important part of the logic presented in your initial queries. so I tried to keep your queries untouched to preserve the logic 100% and rather answered specific question - `Is there any elegant way to join/merge these two?`

Comment: Hi, just trying to break your answer step by step and understand it. So at the top select clause, whether we use `Max` or `Min` doesn't really matter. As we have only one record for each subject, we just choose either of these rather than having another `row_number` operation. Is my understanding right?

Comment: In addition, I would like to know whether is there anything that is similar to `NULLS LAST` in Bigquery? I don't wish NULLS to be ranked.

Comment: I did search online and found out about `ignore nulls` but not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want conditional aggregation:

```
select t2.subject_id, t2.icu_id,
       min(case when t2.item_id in (1, 2) then t2.value end) as value_1,
       min(case when t2.item_id in (3, 4) then t2.value end) as value_2
from table_2 t2
group by t2.subject_id, t2.icu_id;
```

Comment: Upvoted.. Thank you... Traveling right now.. Will update the answer soon..